# 4K TV as monitor? What size?

Tags: display

I'm thinking of buying a 4K TV as a monitor, but I'm unsure of what size makes sense.  My 27" WQHD monitor has a PPI of ~108 and it seems somewhat small. I've seen people buying the Seiko 39" and the Seiko 50", which is the better size.

Additionally the higher quality TVs don't seem to come in sizes smaller than 50". Is that usable as a monitor or is it just too big?

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to opinion.  Too big for me might be just right for you.  I personally don't like having a 39" monitor, because I have to move my head so much.  I'm glad your considering the PPI because I believe thats the most important spec in monitors these days.

I guess if you're deciding between the 39" and 50" i'd go with the 39".  But again, that's simply my opinion.

Comment: +1 for the "comes down to opinion". However the distance between you and the screen is also important. 50 inch at a meter from your eyes seems to work fine AND grants you a lot of (table) desk space.